# Exception while downloading URL in google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Part of my application has a map which should display place in map when entered in a auto filled text view.

I could able to handle exception but map is not displaying the correct place, Log cat shows a message saying "Exception while downloading URL".I am not sure where the problem is.

MainActivity

```
public class Autocomplete extends FragmentActivity {
    AutoCompleteTextView atvPlaces;
    DownloadTask placesDownloadTask;
    DownloadTask placeDetailsDownloadTask;
    ParserTask placesParserTask;
    ParserTask placeDetailsParserTask;
    GoogleMap googleMap;

    final int PLACES=0;
    final int PLACES_DETAILS=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_autocomplete);
// Getting a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView
        atvPlaces = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);
        atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);

// Adding textchange listener
        atvPlaces.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
// Creating a DownloadTask to download Google Places matching "s"
                placesDownloadTask = new DownloadTask(PLACES);

// Getting url to the Google Places Autocomplete api
                String url = getAutoCompleteUrl(s.toString());

// Start downloading Google Places
// This causes to execute doInBackground() of DownloadTask class
                placesDownloadTask.execute(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

// Setting an item click listener for the AutoCompleteTextView dropdown list
        atvPlaces.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int index,
                                    long id) {

                ListView lv = (ListView) arg0;
                SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) arg0.getAdapter();

                HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItem(index);

// Creating a DownloadTask to download Places details of the selected place
                placeDetailsDownloadTask = new DownloadTask(PLACES_DETAILS);

// Getting url to the Google Places details api
                String url = getPlaceDetailsUrl(hm.get("reference"));

// Start downloading Google Place Details
// This causes to execute doInBackground() of DownloadTask class
                placeDetailsDownloadTask.execute(url);

            }
        });
    }

    private String getAutoCompleteUrl(String place){

// Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
        String key = "key=AIzaSyCfdXATlz7jtM6MEvy9Xh_3_g_Ivc5ysXE";

// place to be be searched
        String input = "input="+place;

// place type to be searched
        String types = "types=geocode";

// Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

// Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

// Output format
        String output = "json";

// Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }

    private String getPlaceDetailsUrl(String ref){

// Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
        String key = "key=YOUR_API_KEY";

// reference of place
        String reference = "reference="+ref;

// Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

// Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = reference+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

// Output format
        String output = "json";

// Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

 // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

// Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        private int downloadType=0;

        // Constructor
        public DownloadTask(int type){
            this.downloadType = type;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

// For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
// Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            switch(downloadType){
                case PLACES:
// Creating ParserTask for parsing Google Places
                    placesParserTask = new ParserTask(PLACES);

// Start parsing google places json data
// This causes to execute doInBackground() of ParserTask class
                    placesParserTask.execute(result);

                    break;

                case PLACES_DETAILS :
// Creating ParserTask for parsing Google Places
                    placeDetailsParserTask = new ParserTask(PLACES_DETAILS);

// Starting Parsing the JSON string
// This causes to execute doInBackground() of ParserTask class
                    placeDetailsParserTask.execute(result);
            }
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>> {

        int parserType = 0;

        public ParserTask(int type){
            this.parserType = type;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<HashMap<String, String>> list = null;

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                switch(parserType){
                    case PLACES :
                        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();
// Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                        list = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);
                        break;
                    case PLACES_DETAILS :
                        PlaceDetailsJSONParser placeDetailsJsonParser = new PlaceDetailsJSONParser();
// Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                        list = placeDetailsJsonParser.parse(jObject);
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return list;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            switch(parserType){
                case PLACES :
                    String[] from = new String[] { "description"};
                    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

// Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView
                    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);

// Setting the adapter
                    atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;
                case PLACES_DETAILS :
                    HashMap<String, String> hm = result.get(0);

// Getting latitude from the parsed data
                    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(hm.get("lat"));

// Getting longitude from the parsed data
                    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(hm.get("lng"));

// Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of the activity_main.xml
                    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

// Getting GoogleMap from SupportMapFragment
                    googleMap = fm.getMap();

                    LatLng point = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                    CameraUpdate cameraPosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point);
                    CameraUpdate cameraZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(5);

// Showing the user input location in the Google Map
                    googleMap.moveCamera(cameraPosition);
                    googleMap.animateCamera(cameraZoom);

                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                    options.position(point);
                    options.title("Position");
                    options.snippet("Latitude:"+latitude+",Longitude:"+longitude);

// Adding the marker in the Google Map
                    googleMap.addMarker(options);

                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

ParseDetailsJsonParser.java

```
package zybo.example.ramz.map_webview;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class PlaceDetailsJSONParser {

/** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list */
public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    Double lat = Double.valueOf(0);
    Double lng = Double.valueOf(0);

    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    try {
        lat = (Double)jObject.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").get("lat");
        lng = (Double)jObject.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").get("lng");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    hm.put("lat", Double.toString(lat));
    hm.put("lng", Double.toString(lng));

    list.add(hm);

    return list;
}
}
```

Logcat

```
 Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016   + 62ca4eb + acd831d + 9f8b442 + e027a02 + cba30ba + 53c303a + a649d79 +  23e16f8 + 5e97da7 + cbd2a44 + 33d072a + 7aacf06 + 72b33e7 + 28f6f60 +  b4c13d8 +  NOTHING
09-30 14:44:58.321    2965-3120/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview    I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-30 14:44:58.390    2965-3120/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-30 14:44:58.485    2965-3120/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview V/RenderScript﹕ Application requested CPU execution
09-30 14:44:58.498    2965-3120/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview V/RenderScript﹕ 0xb82914f0 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
09-30 14:45:05.291    2965-3043/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview  D/Volley﹕ [8830] a.a: HTTP response for request=<[ ]  https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api 0x99e6744e NORMAL 1>  [lifetime=7134], [size=60], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
09-30 14:45:05.298    2965-2965/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview D/Volley﹕ [1] p.b: 7147 ms: [ ] https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api 0x99e6744e NORMAL 1
09-30 14:45:05.712    2965-3044/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview D/Volley﹕ [8831] a.a: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://csi.gstatic.com/csi?s=maps_android_api&v=3&action=map_start_up&it=map_load.1581,on_create.1,on_resume.1,init.378&irt=1581,379,399,378 0x4d844933 NORMAL 2> [lifetime=6368], [size=0], [rc=204], [retryCount=0]
09-30 14:45:05.759    2965-2965/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview D/Volley﹕ [1] p.b: 6416 ms: [ ] https://csi.gstatic.com/csi?s=maps_android_api&v=3&action=map_start_up&it=map_load.1581,on_create.1,on_resume.1,init.378&irt=1581,379,399,378 0x4d844933 NORMAL 2
09-30 14:45:14.452    2965-3124/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview D/Exception while downloading url﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Delhi, India&types=geocode&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCfdXATlz7jtM6MEvy9Xh_3_g_Ivc5ysXE
09-30 14:45:14.459    2965-3124/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview D/Background Task﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference
09-30 14:45:17.503    2965-3124/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview D/Exception﹕ org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
09-30 14:45:17.516    2965-3124/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for result
09-30 14:45:17.519    2965-3124/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
09-30 14:45:17.519    2965-3124/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
09-30 14:45:17.520    2965-3124/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview W/System.err﹕ at  zybo.example.ramz.map_webview.PlaceDetailsJSONParser.parse(PlaceDetailsJSONParser.java:25)
09-30 14:45:17.520    2965-3124/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview W/System.err﹕ at zybo.example.ramz.map_webview.Autocomplete$ParserTask.doInBackground(Autocomplete.java:280)
09-30 14:45:17.520    2965-3124/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview W/System.err﹕ at zybo.example.ramz.map_webview.Autocomplete$ParserTask.doInBackground(Autocomplete.java:254)
09-30 14:45:17.520    2965-3124/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
09-30 14:45:17.521    2965-3124/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-30 14:45:17.521    2965-3124/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview W/System.err﹕ at  android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-30 14:45:17.521    2965-3124/zybo.example.ramz.map_webview   W/System.err﹕ at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
```